# Ansible: how to iterate over couples of key/value to do string replacements in multiple files

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have multiple configuration files that contain tags which I want to replace with environment-specific values. My files look like:

```
confId1:@DESTPATH1@:@USER1@:@PASSWORD1@
confId2:@DESTPATH2@:@USER2@:@PASSWORD2@
```

The values to use are in a tag file (yaml) located on the target server.

```
DEV.yml:
---
DESTPATH1: /my/dest/path1
DESTPATH2: /my/dest/path2
USER1: mydevuser1
USER2: mydevuser2
PASSWORD1: 123456
PASSWORD2: 654321
```

I have an ansible playbook that deploys the configuration files to the selected target. First I read the remote tag file with slurp:

```
- name: slurp tag file
  slurp:
    src: "/path/to/tag/DEV.yml"
  register: slurped
```

I can easily access an already known key to display its value:

```
- debug:
    msg: "slurped: {{ (slurped.content|b64decode|from_yaml).DESTPATH1 }}"
```

And can then replace the tag @DESTPATH1@ with its value:

```
- name: replace tags
  replace:
    dest: "/path/to/my/conf/file1.conf"
    regexp: "@DESTPATH1@"
    replace: "{{ (slurped.content|b64decode|from_yaml).DESTPATH1 }}"
```

Now let's consider that:
- I don't know which are the keys in the tag file, so I have to iterate over them.
- There are multiple configuration files in which the tags have to be replaced. Those are listed with the ansible find module

```
- name: find conf files
  find:
    paths: "/path/to/my/conf"
    patterns: "*.conf"
  register: confFiles
```

How can this be achieved with an ansible task ? It would look like:

```
- Iterate over the keys found in the tag file.
- For each key, iterate over the conf files and replace @key@ with the corresponding value
```

Comment: Are you generating both the config files & tags files from Ansible? If so, I would look into the Ansible templating system to generate the config files. And skip having a tag file entirely.

Comment: The playbook clones in a tmp dir a git repo containing 1 tag file per environment and a set of config files. Then depending on the environment, the corresponding tag file is loaded to update the config files, which are eventually moved to the application directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself, it looks like I just had to ask here to find a solution by myself :)

First I changed the tag file syntax:

```
---
tags:
  - tkey: DESTPATH1
    tvalue: /my/dest/path1
  - tkey: DESTPATH2
    tvalue: /my/dest/path2
  - tkey: USER1
    tvalue: mydevuser1
  - tkey: USER2
    tvalue: mydevuser2
  - tkey: PASSWORD1
    tvalue: 123456
  - tkey: PASSWORD2
    tvalue: 654321
```

Then the task that does what I wanted:

```
- name: replace tag.key with tag.value
  replace:
    dest: "{{item[1].path}}"
    regexp: "@{{item[0].tkey}}@"
    replace: "{{item[0].tvalue}}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{(slurped.content|b64decode|from_yaml).tags}}"
    - "{{confFiles.files}}"
```

Comment: ok for a small amount of replacement one can consider this solution as working. Now that I tested with real data it appears that it takes ages, when a simple sed command would have run within a second...

Comment: Have you considered using something like [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) to handle the templating on the servers? (Or a similar templating solution - you could still trigger this from Ansible, but as you experienced, Ansible might not be the best solution for doing the replacements in the files.)

Comment: I will look into it, it might help indeed :)